# apt-get and linux header error

Tags: apt, kernel, linux-headers

I tried to do a 'sudo apt-get install mercurial' and this is the error I got.

Kernel version: 4.8.0-34-generic

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:   linux-headers-4.8.0-39 linux-image-generic thermald Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. The following additional packages will be installed:   libjs-excanvas mercurial-common Suggested packages:   qct kdiff3 | kdiff3-qt | kompare | meld | tkcvs | mgdiff python-mysqldb   python-pygments python-openssl The following NEW packages will be installed:   libjs-excanvas mercurial mercurial-common 0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 175 not upgraded. 5 not fully installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/2,004 kB of archives. After this operation, 10.6 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y Selecting previously unselected package libjs-excanvas. (Reading database ... 208219 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack .../0-libjs-excanvas_0.r3-4_all.deb ... Unpacking libjs-excanvas (0.r3-4) ... Selecting previously unselected package mercurial-common. Preparing to unpack .../1-mercurial-common_3.9.1-1_all.deb ... Unpacking mercurial-common (3.9.1-1) ... Selecting previously unselected package mercurial. Preparing to unpack .../2-mercurial_3.9.1-1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking mercurial (3.9.1-1) ... Setting up libjs-excanvas (0.r3-4) ... Setting up linux-image-4.8.0-22-generic (4.8.0-22.24) ... Running depmod. update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later) Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled  (4.8.0-22.24 was configured last, according to dpkg) Not updating image symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled  (4.8.0-22.24 was configured last, according to dpkg) Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d. run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-22-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-22-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic dkms: WARNING: Linux headers are missing, which may explain the above failures.
      please install the linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic package to fix this. run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools
4.8.0-22-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-22-generic W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915 W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915 run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils
4.8.0-22-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.8.0-22-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.8.0-22-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.8.0-22-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: If: not found run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127 Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.8.0-22-generic.postinst line 1052. dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.8.0-22-generic (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2 Setting up mercurial-common (3.9.1-1) ... Setting up mercurial (3.9.1-1) ...

Creating config file /etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/hgext.rc with new version Setting up linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic (4.8.0-39.42) ... Running depmod. update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later) initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-39-generic ) points to /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-39-generic  (/boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-39-generic)
-- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic.postinst line 491. vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic ) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic  (/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic.postinst line 491. Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d. run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic dkms: WARNING: Linux headers are missing, which may explain the above failures.
      please install the linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic package to fix this. run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools
4.8.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-39-generic run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.8.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.8.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.8.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.8.0-39-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-39-generic /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: If: not found run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127 Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic.postinst line 1052. dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2 Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ... dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:  linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic; however:  Package linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
        dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.8.0-39-generic:  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-39-generic depends on linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic; however:   Package linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-39-generic (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.8.0-22-generic:  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-22-generic depends on linux-image-4.8.0-22-generic; however:   Package linux-image-4.8.0-22-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-22-generic (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing:  linux-image-4.8.0-22-generic  linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic  linux-image-generic  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-39-generic  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-22-generic E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to install all the headers and nothing changed. How can I fix this ?

Comment: The error message clearly includes a suggestion to resolve the problem: `please install the linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic package to fix this`. Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: The program output listing is very difficult to read with the mangled line breaks. Could you please run the command again and [edit] your question to replace the current listing with a *full, verbatim* copy of the command including its original line breaks? You can select, copy and paste terminal content (as well as most dialogue messages) in Ubuntu into arbitrary text fields, e. g. the editor box on AskUbuntu.